# Django Translation - invalid token in plural form when running server

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

Django version 2.2.6; gettext 0.20 in Windows Environment

I start using Python and Django to develop a webapp where translation is needed. Following tutorials, I ran makemessages and compilemessages without errors. Then, when I try to run the server I have the following error :

```
ValueError: invalid token in plural form : Expression at getttext.py line 93.
```

I already tried to flush and recreate my venv, removing my po/mo files and running the server, the error is still the same. It looks like Django mo files are causing this error and I don't know why. Probably a version mismatch between Python, Django and Gettext but I don't know how to fix it.

Can you help ?

Comment: See this link https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html

Comment: Thanks but it looks like it's not an error with my mo files (same errors when I deleted it) but mo files coming from Django itself so...